# MYSQL Query generating multiplication of existing value in table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to do a mysql query to update a table with some values in order of ID, i have sucess in the first time (generate 38 result row) but when i execute this again, this multiplicate the existing value in the table (38x38 = 1444 row result) repeting the already existing product_id in new ID rows.....

i want to insert to this table, only unique product_id from the another target table, and group by the ID [1,2,3,4,5, and dont repeat this too]

the code:

```
/* add all eligible customers to temporary table */
INSERT INTO `temp_wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads`
(`product_id`, `subscription_id`)

  SELECT posts.ID AS product_id, downn.subscription_id AS subscription_id
  FROM wp_posts posts
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads downn
  WHERE posts.post_type = 'product'
    AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
;
```

in the print you can see the generated issue:

(https://prntscr.com/s2zhil)

EDIT:  Work perfect with the code from the @GordonLinoff answer,but after run and add a new product and run the query again the `ID` is dont by a order (appear to "jump/burn some ids", how i order by unique id's too? and as you can see  :
http://prntscr.com/s31rrq

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new rows. If you want to update existing rows, use `UPDATE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sir, i updated the question, can u see the result?

Comment: Where do you check for duplicates in the query?

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the original version of the question.

You can add a unique index on `productid` and then use `on duplicate key`.

```
alter table temp_wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads
    add constraint unq_temp_wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads_product_id
        unique(product_id);

INSERT INTO temp_wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads(`product_id`, `subscription_id`)

    SELECT p.ID AS product_id, d.subscription_id AS subscription_id
    FROM wp_posts posts p JOIN
         wp_woocommerce_subscription_downloads d
         ON p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE subscription_id = d.subscription_id;
```

That said, I suspect that you might also be missing a `JOIN` condition on the table -- say by post or product.

Comment: i updated the question, its perfect now, but how i can order the ids and dont burn them?